# SpecFlow error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop error when running tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow, parallels, apple-m1

I am running Parallels on an M1 MacBook with Visual Studio 2019 installed.  I have installed SpecFlow and setup a new project (using 'SpecFlow Project' option).

Without making any changes I try and run the default calculator test that is created. I get the following error in the logs:

> 2021-03-08T15:48:00.9438755+00:00;Thread#12;Error;Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException thrown during serialization: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'ManifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'Summary.FrameworkErrorException.InnerException.TargetSite.Module.Assembly'.

I suspect this may be an M1 chip MacBook compatibility issue with SpecFlow (despite running on Parallels) but wondered if anyone had managed to fix this error when running SpecFlow feature files?

Here is the full log details:

```
2021-03-08T15:47:58.3341220+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;SpecFlow+Runner execution started
2021-03-08T15:47:58.3348037+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;SpecFlow+Runner 3.7.3 in Framework netcore31 in x64 mode execution started
2021-03-08T15:47:58.3348321+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;TestAdapter Location: \\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.dll
2021-03-08T15:47:58.3387007+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Current UserName: 'charlieseligman', MachineName: 'CHARLIESELI0D9D'
2021-03-08T15:47:58.3980081+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;SpecRun: running tests in \\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DeleteProject.dll
2021-03-08T15:47:58.3987441+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Output folder configured to "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\TestResults" (default)
2021-03-08T15:47:58.4000208+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Profile:
2021-03-08T15:47:58.4811167+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Log file path: \\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\TestResults\Unnamed project__2021-03-08T154758.log
2021-03-08T15:47:58.4915350+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Checking activation
2021-03-08T15:47:58.6828131+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Activated.
2021-03-08T15:47:58.6836331+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Activation check completed
2021-03-08T15:47:58.6840017+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Starting test run
2021-03-08T15:47:58.8609352+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Discovering target: Default
2021-03-08T15:47:58.8926851+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Discovering tests from assembly: \\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DeleteProject.dll
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5200560+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Discovered tests from assembly: \\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\DeleteProject.dll
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5241342+00:00:Test Suite Dump
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5268815+00:00:#0: Unnamed project/ -
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5269775+00:00:#1: Default -
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5269991+00:00:#2: DeleteProject -
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5270078+00:00:#3: Calculator -
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5295451+00:00:#4: Add two numbers - TestAssembly:DeleteProject/Feature:Calculator/Scenario:Add+two+numbers
2021-03-08T15:47:59.5296593+00:00:End: Test Suite Dump
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6521231+00:00:Thread#0:Scheduler: get next test for thread 0
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6555193+00:00:Thread#:Scheduler: testitem #4 from normal test queue
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6556918+00:00:Thread#0:Scheduler: considering testitem #4 for thread 0
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6612955+00:00:Thread#0:TestItem#4:testItemMatchesCurrentTestThread:UnSpecific
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6613414+00:00:Thread#0:TestItem#4:runsOnOneOtherThreadSpecific:False
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6613711+00:00:Thread#0:TestItem#4:runsOnOneOtherThreadUnspecific:False
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6614160+00:00:Thread#0:Scheduler: using testitem #4 for thread 0
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6626078+00:00:Thread#0:Scheduler: Test #4 is scheduled for thread
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6679526+00:00:Thread#0:Scheduler: with testItemExecutionIndex 0
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6718810+00:00:Thread #0: creating new test thread executor for DeleteProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (target: Default)
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6760463+00:00:Thread #0: Creating test assembly executor for execution model OutProc
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6764966+00:00:Thread #0: Creating test assembly executor for execution model OutProc
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6849249+00:00:Thread #0: using TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.StreamJsonRPC.OutOfProcessTestAssemblyExecutorHost to execute tests
2021-03-08T15:47:59.6893257+00:00:starting Out Of Process Executor
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7161361+00:00:Assembly resolving Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7224767+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' from .deps.json file
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7229450+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' from .deps.json
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7255695+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7265530+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation.dll'
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7268647+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation.exe'
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7270451+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7283263+00:00:TargetFramework: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7296133+00:00:Tfm: netcoreapp3.1
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7296544+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7296666+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation.dll'
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7299356+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Found file '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation.dll' for assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation'
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7557146+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Resolved 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation' to \\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation.dll
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7575144+00:00:Starting callback TCP Rpc server
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7936118+00:00:Asynchronously starting background TCP Rpc Server on port 32768
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7942457+00:00:Started callback TCP Rpc server on port 32768
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7942692+00:00:Starting logger TCP Rpc server
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7965978+00:00:Asynchronously starting background TCP Rpc Server on port 32769
2021-03-08T15:47:59.7966752+00:00:Started logger TCP Rpc server on port 32769
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0019442+00:00:Executing test executor at 'dotnet' 'exec "Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Executor.anycpu.netcoreapp3_1.dll" --remoteRunnerPid 9372 --uniqueId "2021-03-08T154758" --outputFolder "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\TestResults" --callbackPort 32768 --loggerPort 32769' in 'Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0890899+00:00:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (267): The directory name is invalid.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.OutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsOutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.StreamJsonRPC.OutOfProcessTestAssemblyExecutorHost.Initialize(Int32 threadId, ITestExecutionManager executionManager, IAssemblyReference testAssembly, ITestLogger currentLogger, String testAssemblyFullPath, String testAssemblyConfigFilePath, TestExecutionConfiguration testExecutionConfiguration, String target)
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0989111+00:00:Assembly resolving System.Diagnostics.Process.resources, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0989667+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' from .deps.json file
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0989796+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' from .deps.json
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0989941+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0990299+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0991227+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0992084+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0992221+00:00:TargetFramework: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0993228+00:00:Tfm: netcoreapp3.1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0993370+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0993488+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0994465+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.0995310+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1196236+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1196945+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1197614+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1197866+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1199493+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1199606+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1199957+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1200353+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1201472+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1201569+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1202102+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12\System.Diagnostics.Process.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1202314+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Diagnostics.Process.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1222160+00:00:Assembly resolving System.Diagnostics.Process.resources, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1289902+00:00:Thread #0: Error while unpacking executor: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (267): The directory name is invalid.
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.OutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsOutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.StreamJsonRPC.OutOfProcessTestAssemblyExecutorHost.Initialize(Int32 threadId, ITestExecutionManager executionManager, IAssemblyReference testAssembly, ITestLogger currentLogger, String testAssemblyFullPath, String testAssemblyConfigFilePath, TestExecutionConfiguration testExecutionConfiguration, String target)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.InitializeExecutor(ITestAssemblyExecutor executor, DeploymentContext deploymentContext, IAssemblyReference testAssembly)
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1296638+00:00:test thread #0 error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (267): The directory name is invalid.
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.UnpackTestThreadExecutorInfoResult(IResult`1 testThreadExecutorInfoResult)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.InitializeTestThreadExecutor(IAssemblyReference testAssembly, ExecutionModelSettings executionModelSettings, String testTarget)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.GetThreadExecutor(IAssemblyReference testAssembly, ExecutionModelSettings executionModelSettings, String testTarget)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.GetThreadExecutorForTestItem(TestItem testItem)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.RunNonEmptyTestSuite(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TestThreadState testThreadState)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.Run(ITestExecutionManager executionManagerForRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.AsyncTestThreadRunner.RunSync(TestExecutionManager executionManager, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1326278+00:00:test thread error: TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.SpecRunException: At least one test thread aborted.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (267): The directory name is invalid.
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.UnpackTestThreadExecutorInfoResult(IResult`1 testThreadExecutorInfoResult)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.InitializeTestThreadExecutor(IAssemblyReference testAssembly, ExecutionModelSettings executionModelSettings, String testTarget)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.GetThreadExecutor(IAssemblyReference testAssembly, ExecutionModelSettings executionModelSettings, String testTarget)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.GetThreadExecutorForTestItem(TestItem testItem)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.RunNonEmptyTestSuite(CancellationToken cancellationToken, TestThreadState testThreadState)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.TestThread.Run(ITestExecutionManager executionManagerForRun, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.AsyncTestThreadRunner.RunSync(TestExecutionManager executionManager, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1508426+00:00:Thread#-1: Test #4/0 is started on thread #-1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.1790503+00:00:Thread#-1: Test #4/0 is finished on thread #-1 as Skipped within 0.0224131 seconds
2021-03-08T15:48:00.3852668+00:00:Thread#-1:Scheduler: get next test for thread -1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.3853524+00:00:Thread#:Scheduler: at the end of normal test queue
2021-03-08T15:48:00.3853827+00:00:Thread#-1:Scheduler: enumerator for thread is at end
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4373596+00:00:Assembly resolving System.Net.Sockets.resources, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4374363+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' from .deps.json file
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4374531+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' from .deps.json
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4374750+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4374847+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\System.Net.Sockets.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4376016+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\System.Net.Sockets.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4376783+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4376925+00:00:TargetFramework: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4377566+00:00:Tfm: netcoreapp3.1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4377677+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4377771+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\System.Net.Sockets.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4378523+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1\System.Net.Sockets.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4379174+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder '\\Mac\Home\Desktop\DeleteProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpecFlowPlusRunner\netcoreapp3.1'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4389215+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4389474+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12\System.Net.Sockets.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4389873+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12\System.Net.Sockets.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4390265+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4390935+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4391047+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12\System.Net.Sockets.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4391285+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12\System.Net.Sockets.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4391453+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4392083+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4392152+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12\System.Net.Sockets.resources.dll'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4392381+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Trying to resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12\System.Net.Sockets.resources.exe'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4392567+00:00:[AssemblyCache] Could not resolve 'System.Net.Sockets.resources' in folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\3.1.12'
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4399068+00:00:Assembly resolving System.Net.Sockets.resources, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4437138+00:00;Thread#12;Info;test run finished
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4449837+00:00;Thread#12;Info;publishing test results
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4458952+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Not publishing results.
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4465061+00:00;Thread#12;Info;test results published
2021-03-08T15:48:00.4466864+00:00;Thread#12;Info;generating reports
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9438755+00:00;Thread#12;Error;Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException thrown during serialization: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'ManifestModule' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'Summary.FrameworkErrorException.InnerException.TargetSite.Module.Assembly'.
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object value)
at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Services.JsonNetSerializer.Serialize[T](T value, FSharpOption`1 target)
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9452640+00:00;Thread#12;Error;Failed writing reporting data to file "C:\Users\charlieseligman\AppData\Local\Temp\4f907254-0990-467d-8b7f-bacc30f9aac6".
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9568638+00:00;Thread#12;Info;Failed generating reports
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9703745+00:00:Total: 1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9736996+00:00:Succeeded: 0
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9742691+00:00:Ignored: 0
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9747124+00:00:Pending: 0
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9747483+00:00:Skipped: 1
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9752032+00:00:Failed: 0
2021-03-08T15:48:00.9772309+00:00;VSTestExecutionThread;Info;Adding attachments to VSTest
========== End of log file ==========
```

Answer (score 2):

I just answered the original question at https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/360014907078-Newtonsoft-Json-JsonSerializationException-Self-referencing-loop-error?page=1#community_comment_360004000098

It looks like a bug on our side. As a workaround, you can disable report generation.

For that, put this into your srProfile file

```
<Report disable="true"/>
```

From https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-runner/en/latest/Profile/Report.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out, that I created hooks as non-static. The hook methods need to be static.

```
[BeforeFeature(Order = 0)]
public static void EmptyStorageFolder()
{
}
```